# Compute the fundamental matrix from two given camera matrices

Tags: matrices, matlab

Given two camera matrices, $P_1$ and $P_2$, compute the fundamental matrix $F$.

The formula for $F$ is $[K't]_x  K'RK^{-1}$.

I am confused by the first part of the formula, $[K't]_x$, due to lack of mathematical knowledge. What does the subscript '$x$' mean?

Matlab may be used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post: http://sourishghosh.com/2016/fundamental-matrix-from-camera-matrices/

The subscript "$x$" denotes a cross-product matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "skew symmetric matrix". $[t]_X$ is a cross-product expressed as a matrix. Think for moment: a line is the cross-product of two points (in homogeneous co-ordinates). The fundamental matrix is telling you where epipolar lines are. Find two points, and you have the line (by cross product).